# Can't get output in Notepad++

Tags: c, gcc, notepad++

I am new to learning programming. Ive set up MinGW and have added the plugin.
I tried running this basic code

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  puts("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

but it doesnt seem to return anything. This is what the console log shows

```
cc -o hello.exe hello.c
gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
Process started (PID=14948) >>>
<<< Process finished (PID=14948). (Exit code 0)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this help? : https://daleswanson.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-compile-c-code-in-notepad-with.html

Comment: Try: 
`$ gcc hello.c -o hello`
And then run `./hello`

Comment: Compile with `gcc -o hello.exe hello.c`, then run the resulting .exe by typing `hello.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not return anything because `C` is a *compiled* language, you just compiled it, for it to return something you need to run it.

To run it open the folder where you compiled it and 2 clicks on the `file hello.exe`